# How to give browser specific styles in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I want to give browser specific styles in magento. The menus in the header are given `margin-top:-3px;` It works well in chrome. But in firefox I need to give `margin-top:-40px;`
Someone kindly help me.
I also tried :
    `@-moz-document url-prefix() {
 #custommenu { margin-top:-40px; }
 }`

Comment: check here http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-create-browser-specific-css-rules-styles.html#gref

Comment: It didnt work for me. Kindly help

Comment: Which firefox version are you testing in? 

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/

Comment: @Ramya then try this http://browserhacks.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution

```
body:not(:-moz-handler-blocked) .logo {
    width:486px;
  }
```

With your values, I´ve just copied this and it worked fine on my local version.

Comment: Its working fine. Thanks. But how can we give it in media queries?